# Does this cell contain these numbers MATLAB

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have a cell 4x1,

```
{{1,2,3};{2,3};{1,2,3};{2,3}}
```

How can I found out, which cells contain `{2,3}`

i.e. `[1,1,1,1]` for the above example.

All of the cells contain the {2,3} in some form.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're only interested in numbers, it's odd to store them in cells... To use a function like `ismember` you'll have to deploy `cell2mat`. Then this gives your result:

```
A = {{1,2,3};{2,3};{1,2,3};{2,3}};
tgt = [2,3];
cellfun( @(x) all( ismember( tgt, cell2mat(x) ) ), A )
```

If instead you stored the numbers in numeric arrays, this would be more efficient

```
A = {[1,2,3];[2,3];[1,2,3];[2,3]};
cellfun( @(x) all( ismember( tgt, x ) ), A )
```